# How to bind asset with account

Tags: hyperledger-iroha

According [entity-relationship model](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_concepts/er_model.html) asset can be bound to the account. But I did not find command to do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the AddAssetQuantity command or just a TranferAsset, if the account is in the domain you can automatically access those Assets.